# JQuery UI, catch in script draggable element drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have JQuery UI draggable items and they connect with sortable area items. Draggable items drop clone in sortable items.

How i can catch in script droped draggable element to sortable area event, for change or manipulate his properties?

Comment: present your code and if possible a jsfiddle demo

Comment: @YoYo jsfiddle work in https and try load jquery from other not https site, and chrome throw error:
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: jsfiddle has default jquery load functionality . You can just post your code here https://jsfiddle.net/c8L9v5bp/1/

Comment: @YoYo have error - $(...).sortable is not a function, i think it's because jquery ui not loaded, and why it is not loaded, I wrote in first comment

Comment: @YoYo if u dont know about draggable+sortable u can see in jqueryui example http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/draggable/sortable.html i have same code

Comment: but why dont you provide your code here atleast

Comment: can you use this fiddle now https://jsfiddle.net/c8L9v5bp/2/ ,, Actually even Jquery Ui file was suppose to be selected too . Now your code should work

Comment: @YoYo i'm alredy end search answers about this problem, and understood what it is not have standart solution and coders resolve this with different way tricks.